# AppleScript : Execute JavaScript on every Safari Tab/Window

Tags: applescript, safari

How to run JavaScript in every safari TAB?

I used to have a script with find a specific tab and run javascript but I have some issue and I was wondering how can I simply run some JavaScript in every tab and window (safari) instead.

```
tell application "Safari" to tell document 1 to do JavaScript ¬
    "document.getElementsByClassName('Demo')[0].click();"
```

I though running a script to tell how many tab and create a loops but that doesn't work as I have multiple window of safari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the **Ask Question** *button* that's in the upper right hand corner of the page, like in this question, and having multiple *windows* each with multiple *tabs* to a **Ask Different** web page, as well as some non-related pages...

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* clicks the **Ask Question** *button* on every page having the *button*. It doesn't matter what *window* or *tab* has focus, the *button* on all that have it gets clicked.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
tell application "Safari" to tell tabs of windows to ¬
    do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('ws-nowrap s-btn s-btn__primary')[0].click();"
```

Answer (score 0):

I still need to find a way to do that on every window but otherwise for a single window I found this :

```
tell application "Safari"
    repeat
        repeat with i from (count of tabs of window 1) to 1 by -1
            set thisTab to tab i of window 1
            set current tab of window 1 to thisTab
            tell application "Safari" to tell document 1 to do JavaScript ¬
                "document.getElementsByClassName('demo')[0].click();"
            delay 0.1
        end repeat
        exit repeat
    end repeat
end tell
```